# Construct a CMTime with Drop Frame / NTSC Video for AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset, cmtime, avassetimagegenerator

### Context:

Suppose I have a file `video.mov` which has an NTSC frame rate of `29.97`. It uses drop frame for the timecodes, which means that for every minute except the 10th minute, the timecode skips forward by 2 frames.

### Questions:

In Swift 5.9, I want to use `AVAssetImageGenerator`'s `image(at:)` method to grab an image of the 3,450th frame of this video. The method accepts a `CMTime` struct, which provides a specific *time* in the video at which the image should be captured.

If I understand correctly, that time should be `3450 / (30000/1001)` = `115.115` seconds. Expressed in integers for `CMTime`, that becomes: `(3450 * 1001) / 30000`.

1. Is this the correct way to handle NTSC video? I gather `CMTime` is concerned with just absolute time, not timecodes, so drop frames don't matter?
2. Is there a better API to use (without time conversion) given that I know the exact frame that needs to be captured?
3. If I do NOT know the native frame rate for a video file, is `AVAsset`'s `preferredRate` API the appropriate way to retrieve that?